# Header with the table description

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have a document created by **python-docx (version 0.8.11)**, to which I need to add some rows in a table. Whenever the table exceeds the page border I'll need to separate them in two tables and add a header with the table description. I couldn't find information about how I can manage that. Does anybody have any idea how to help me out using python-docx or another library?

Comment: When you say "page border" do you mean page width or height?

Comment: I mean height. :)

Comment: There is no way to "measure" how tall your table has become, have a search on "python-docx detect page breaks" to understand why. But I believe the feature you're looking for is "repeat header rows" in which Word does the repeating of the header rows of a table after a mid-table page break. Unfortunately this feature is not implemented in `python-docx` at present, so you'd need to find a way to implement that yourself if you really need it.